# how to set Content-type: application/json in yii extension?

Tags: curl, yii, yii-extensions

**I am using yii extension for rest API.But I am not able to set content-type in header information.**

[using this YII extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-curl/)

Please,provide solution of it?

My REST file test.php code:

```
<?php 
echo "In rest api";
print_r($_SERVER);
?>
```

I called it from Yii CURL:

```
echo $output = Yii::app()->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('CONTENT_TYPE:   application/json'))
->post("localhost/test.php");
```

I got following output:

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 13 Nov 2013 18:14:10 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.8
Content-Length: 311
Content-Type: text/html


In rest apiArray
(
[HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20110619   Firefox/5.0
[HTTP_HOST] => localhost
[HTTP_ACCEPT] => */*
[CONTENT_LENGTH] => 143
[HTTP_EXPECT] => 100-continue
[CONTENT_TYPE] => multipart/form-data; boundary=----------------------------f0f331e79d34
[PATH] => C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\system32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\Dell\DW WLAN Card;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\WIDCOMM\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files (x86)\cvsnt;
[SystemRoot] => C:\Windows
[COMSPEC] => C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
[PATHEXT] => .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
[WINDIR] => C:\Windows
[SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
[SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.8
[SERVER_NAME] => localhost
[SERVER_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
[SERVER_PORT] => 80
[REMOTE_ADDR] => 127.0.0.1
[DOCUMENT_ROOT] => C:/wamp/www/
[SERVER_ADMIN] => admin@localhost
[SCRIPT_FILENAME] => C:/wamp/www/testforget.php
[REMOTE_PORT] => 1287
[GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
[SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
[REQUEST_METHOD] => POST
[QUERY_STRING] => 
[REQUEST_URI] => /testforget.php
[SCRIPT_NAME] => /testforget.php
[PHP_SELF] => /testforget.php
[REQUEST_TIME] => 1384365808
```

)

I got

```
[CONTENT_TYPE] => multipart/form-data;
```

why I got content_type this,But it should get [CONTENT_TYPE] => application/json as I set it in my request?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Yii::app()->curl
             ->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: application/json'))
             ->post("localhost/testforget.php",$data);
```

Comment: $data=array('value'=>'123');
$output = Yii::app()->curl->post("http://localhost/testforget.php",$data);

Comment: with this how can I set header type.

Comment: when I do it I got this $output = Yii::app()->curl->setOption(CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 'Content-type: application/json')->post("http://localhost/testforget.php",$data);

Comment: I got "curl_setopt() [<a href='function.curl-setopt'>function.curl-setopt</a>]: You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, CURLOPT_QUOTE, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES and CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE" arguments this error

Comment: got this error "curl_setopt() [<a href='function.curl-setopt'>function.curl-setopt</a>]: You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, CURLOPT_QUOTE, CURLOPT_HTTP200ALIASES and CURLOPT_POSTQUOTE arguments"

Answer (score 0):

Looking through [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) I have found, that `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` with `Content-type:...` option is applied on **your request**, but not on the server response. To change server response headers, in your `test.php` file add the next line

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```

before you echo any data. And use `json_encode()` on data, you will echo.